# How to dynamically render images with different ext?

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables

I have a table in mysql that has a column called articleID. When a new article is created and uploaded, an image is added to the server with the filename of the articleID.

My only problem is that when trying to display the images, some of the images are png, some are jpeg/jpg and so the img source extension changes. Is there any way to make it so that the extensions are dynamic too?

My PHP code:

```
$spotlight .= '<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 article-thumb">
                    <img src="img/articleImages/'.$articleID.'.jpg" alt="">
                    <h2 class="article-title">' . $articleTitle. '</h2>
                    <p class="article-intro">'.$articleSummary.'</p>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                    <a href="writers/matt-ellis.php" class="meta-link">'.$articleWriter.'</a>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> '. $articlePostDate .'
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                    <a href="categories/sport.php" class="meta-link">'.$articleCategory.'</a>
                    <br><br>
                    <button class="btn btn-custom">Read More</button>
                </div>';
```

Comment: I would suggest saving the full file name in the row, or maybe only the extension

Comment: @RiggsFolly and then call that value from the table using sql and saving as a local variable?

Comment: Well yes, if its related to the article, in the article table

Comment: Otherwise you are going to have to write a, probably very slow, file list to get the correct filename from the file system

Comment: @RiggsFolly Okay thank you!